# Symfony 2.1 enable/disable stack traces

Tags: symfony-2.1

Few moments ago I realised that symfony prints out all exceptions in my prod env. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of looking, it seems this is how to (there is probably a better solution but I couldn't find it).

Under `web/app.php`, change `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` - the `true` here sets `display_errors` to true, so just change it to `false`.

If that fails, you should ensure that display_errors is turned off (if it's production, probably best done in php.ini itself rather than using `ini_set`).